# Filling a TableView with Content from the database

Tags: java, sql, database, javafx

I know this is asked 100 times already, but I still cant manage to make it work.
I want the TableView filled with the things that are stored in my database.

I got my FXML with an empty TableView (first question here: should I set the columns already? )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sopraFx.extended.view.UserEditView">
    <children>
        <MenuBar layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="507.0">

        </MenuBar>
        <Button fx:id="logoutButton" layoutX="506.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCloseButtonAction" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Zurück" />
      <TextField fx:id="tableEditName" layoutX="369.0" layoutY="59.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="124.0" promptText="Username" />
      <TextField fx:id="tableEditPassword" layoutX="369.0" layoutY="115.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="124.0" promptText="Password" />
      <TextField fx:id="tableEditEmail" layoutX="369.0" layoutY="165.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="124.0" promptText="E-Mail" />
      <Button fx:id="editButton" defaultButton="true" layoutX="527.0" layoutY="363.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="64.0" text="you want to edit" />
      <TableView fx:id="userEditTable" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="311.0" prefWidth="286.0">

      </TableView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This right here is my Method to get the things out of the database and into the TableView. I got som System out prints to check if it gives me the right things and it does. Problem is that I get NullPointerExpections at " tableview.getColums().addAll.col "

This is the code:

```
    public void initialize() {


        TableView tableview = getUserTable();
        ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
        Connection c;
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try{
            c = Database.getConnection();
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM User";
            ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

            for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
                final int j = i;
                TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
                col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){
                    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                    }
                });

                tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);
                System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
            }
            while(rs.next()){
                //Iterate Row
                ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                    //Iterate Column
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
                data.add(row);

            }
            //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
            tableview.setItems(data);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
        }

    }
```

I worked through that tutorial to get the method: http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/comment-page-1/

Edit:

In the controller i have the following method to show the scene.

```
 private Parent sceneUserEdit;
 private UserEditView viewUserEdit;
public Parent userEditScene() throws SQLException {
    Stage userEditStage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../view/UserEdit.fxml"));
    try {
        sceneUserEdit = loader.load();
        userEditStage.setTitle("SoPra JavaFX");
        userEditStage.setScene(new Scene(sceneUserEdit, 600, 400));
        userEditStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    viewUserEdit = loader.getController();
    viewUserEdit.setSimpleController(this);
    initialize();


    return sceneUserEdit;

}
```

the initialize method is in the Controller. 
in the UserEditView class I got FXMLs for The whole TableView and for each TableColumn combined with getters for those

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<User> userTable;
public TableView<User> getUserTable(){return userTable;}
```

Comment: So `tableView` is null? No-one can really diagnose that from the code you've posted.

Comment: I think he cant find the TableView. In my UserEditView class there is a getter for the TableView

Comment: Yes, I can see that. And clearly it is returning `null`. No-one can possibly tell you why that is happening from the code you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

In your FXML file you have

```xml
<TableView fx:id="userEditTable" ... />
```

but in the controller you have

```
@FXML
private TableView<User> userTable;
```

The name of the field needs to match the `fx:id`.